# VB6 COM returns ADODB.Recordset in byRef Variant. How to retrieve in C#?

Tags: com, vb6, adodb, byref

I'm trying to call this COM method:

```
Public Function DoSomething(ByRef StringStuff As Variant, **ByRef Out_Data As Variant**) As Boolean
```

Out_Data gets defined and populated in the method body as an ADODB.Recordset (2.6).

I've tried several different ways I can think of, but still can't seem to get that recordset  object out, or in for that matter.

Any ideas?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Can you call it using `ref` or `out`?

```
Object StringStuff = "Hello Word";
Object Out_Data = null;
DoSomething(ref StringStuff, ref Out_Data);
// or
DoSomething(out StringStuff, out Out_Data);

//I haven't use ADODB in a long while so convert this to whatever type is necessary
ADODB.Recordset ar = (ADODB.Recordset)Out_Data;
```